# Squeeze dataframe rows with missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to squeeze a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,pd.NA,100],[2,20,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,300],[pd.NA,"bla",400]], columns=["A","B","C"])
df1
      A     B      C
0     1  <NA>  100.0
1     2    20    NaN
2   NaN   NaN  300.0
3  <NA>   bla  400.0
```

into a left-side compact way:

```
    df_out
      A     B      C
0     1   100    NaN
1     2    20    NaN
2   300   NaN    NaN
3   bla   400    NaN
```

Also, it will be nice to convert all missing values from pd.NA to np.nan.
How can do it? Thanks!

Comment: For the NA -> NaN conversion you can always use `df.replace(pd.NA, float('nan'))` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a function with [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) to remove the NaN  and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to push (squeeze) the data to the "left" by removing the aligment.

Then [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to the original A/B/C... and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to reinstate the eventually lost levels (here C would be missing as there is no non-NaN values):

```
df2 = (df1
 .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
 .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(df1.columns)))
 .reindex(columns=df1.columns)
)
```

Or another approach working as the Series level by only dropping the NaNs and adding missing ones in the end:

```
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series((y:=x.dropna().to_list())
                                    +[float('nan')]*(len(df1.columns)-len(y)),
                                    index=df1.columns), axis=1)
```

output:

```
       A      B   C
0      1  100.0 NaN
1      2   20.0 NaN
2  300.0    NaN NaN
3    bla  400.0 NaN
```

Or also possible but without changing the NA to NaN:

```
df2 = df1.T.apply(sorted, key=pd.isna).T
```

output:

```
       A      B     C
0      1  100.0  <NA>
1    2.0   20.0   NaN
2  300.0    NaN   NaN
3    bla  400.0  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

For each row remove missing values in [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), `rename` columns by dictionary and last add missing columns in [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()), axis=1)
         .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(df1.columns)))
         .reindex(df1.columns, axis=1))

print (df)
       A      B   C
0      1  100.0 NaN
1      2   20.0 NaN
2  300.0    NaN NaN
3    bla  400.0 NaN
```

Another idea:

```
df = (df1.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(key=lambda x: x.isna()).to_numpy(), 
                axis=1, 
                result_type='expand')
        .set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1)
        .mask(lambda x: x.isna())
        )
print (df)
       A      B    C
0      1  100.0  NaN
1      2   20.0  NaN
2  300.0    NaN  NaN
3    bla  400.0  NaN
```

---

```
df = (df1.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(key=lambda x: x.isna()).to_numpy(), 
                axis=1, 
                result_type='expand')
        .set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1)
        )
print (df)
       A      B     C
0      1  100.0  <NA>
1      2   20.0   NaN
2  300.0    NaN   NaN
3    bla  400.0  <NA>
```