# Turning multiple binary columns into categorical (with less columns) with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I want to turn these categories into values of categorical columns. The values in each category are the current binary columns present in the data frame. We have : A11, A12.. is a detail of A1 so if the value in A11 ==1 it will necessarily imply having A1==1 but the inverse is not valid.
Respecting the following conditions :

1. maximaum of existing types is 4
2. if A11==1 value of type1 should be equal to 'A11' and we ignore 'A1'
3. if A11==1 and A12==1 we keep both, each one in a different column and ignore 'A1'
4. if A1==1 & A11==0 & A12==0 then type1 should be equal to 'A1' for not having a detailed info A1X
5. if none is equal to 1 then NaN

**What I have :**

```py
df_test=pd.DataFrame({'A1':[1,0,1,1],'A11':[1,0,1,0],'A12':[1,0,1,0],
                      'B1':[0,1,0,0],'B11':[0,1,0,0],
                      'C1':[1,1,0,0],
                      'D1':[0,1,0,1],'D11':[0,1,0,1],'D12':[0,0,0,1],
                      'E1':[0,1,0,1],'E11':[0,0,0,0],'E12':[0,1,0,0],'E13':[0,0,0,0]})
df_test

    A1 A11 A12 B1  B11  C1  D1 D11 D12  E1 E11 E12 E13
0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0
2   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
```

**Desired result I want :**

```py
   type1    type2   type3   type4
0   A11     A12      C1      NaN
1   B11     C1      D11      E12
2   A11     A12     NaN      NaN
3   A1      D11     D12      E1
```

Comment: 1- there is no A12 in your data, 2- why is B11 in the type1/A column?

Comment: Also why is type1 at index 3 "A1"? You said "A1" is only for A1==1 and A11==0 which isn't what happens in row 3.

Comment: @not_speshal I updated my question details to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the full logic, but here is my current understanding: getting the max number for each A/B/C/D type.

You should be able to adapt this for your exact use.

```
df2 = (pd
  # reshape (one could also use a MultiIndex)
 .wide_to_long(df_test.replace(0, float('nan')).reset_index(),
               ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], i='index', j='x')
 .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
 # transform 1s into the column header
 .pipe(lambda d: d.mul(d.columns)
       .replace('', pd.NA)
       .add(d.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str), axis=0))
 # select max code for each initial row
 .groupby(level='index').last()
)
```

output:

```
          A     B     C     D     E
index                              
0       A12  None    C1  None  None
1      None   B11    C1   D11   E12
2       A12  None  None  None  None
3        A1  None  None   D12    E1
```

##### moving the values to the left

```
out = (df2
 .stack()
 .reset_index(1)
 .assign(level_1=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
 .set_index('level_1', append=true)
 [0].unstack('level_1')
 .add_prefix('type')
)
```

Output:

```
  type1 type2 type3 type4
0   A12    C1   NaN   NaN
1   B11    C1   D11   E12
2   A12   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    A1   D12    E1   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway for your response, to clarify a bit, I want columns type1,type2, type3, and type because the maximum of binary values per line is 4 (without taking into consideration original columns A1, B1.. if there is A11, B12..) so I need to fill each column typeX with the existing categories (which can't be more than 4 types per one row) so for this reason, I can't fix A B C D categories names, otherwise, I'll be missing new Infos E, F, G.. while having only NaNs in the 4 existing columns

Comment: Well you could use more categories and then find a way to compress, but anyways, even without this the full logic is not fully clear. Maybe best to try breaking this problem in several steps.

Comment: I updated my question details to make it clearer for you I hope

Comment: The last step of [moving all non-NaN values to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062157/move-non-empty-cells-to-the-left-in-pandas-dataframe) can easily be fine afterwards ;).  This wasn't clear in your initial question as you had NaNs in the middle

Comment: Exaaactlyyy, u got me well now it's what I want to achieve, you have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: If you use my answer, then move the values to the left using one of the answers in the link I posted above, then slice to keep only 4 columns, this should give you what you want. Give it a try

Comment: Here is a more recent approach to [move the values to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422177/squeeze-dataframe-rows-with-missing-values)

Comment: I added an update

Comment: Thank youu so much, although the problem here is when I have many categories starting with the same alphabet It only works for the last one, for example in my description I have A11 and A12 in the first row, I want Both values for A11 (in type1) and A12 (in type2) and then C1 ( in type3) and Nan because no category left (in type4) but you're quiet close to the answer, I need just to handle this issue

Comment: Mary I ask what is this data? Wouldn't it be easier to generate the correct groups in the beginning? To solve the last part you'd need to duplicate the categories for each subcategory. I won't be able to test that now (on my phone).

Comment: (Those are columns I got using one-hot encoding), would you please consider checking it if you are free, I'm still stuck on the same issue we discussed earlier